# How to check browser compatibility

Tags: web-applications, cross-browser, web.py

I've written a web app that uses features that make it incompatible with IE and require minimum versions of Firefox and Chrome.  To check browser compatibility, I'm getting the User-Agent from the headers of the request with web.py and checking the output with a simple regex.

I'm worried though, that changes to the way Chrome or Firefox declares it's User-Agent might break my regex.  Also, since I'm explicitly requiring Firefox or Chrome, I'm probably excluding some browsers that might otherwise be able to use the site.

Is checking User-Agent the right way to go?  How should I go about checking compatibility to ensure only browsers that have sufficient functionality are served?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better do it on client side, browser sniffing is considered bad. The best practice is using conditional comments to add ie# (Internet Explorer version) classname on html to be able to write separate css styles for it, and use [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect supported features.